# Converting an annual Image Collection into a multiband image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have an image collection with 35 years of imagery. Each image in the collection represents a measure of annual NDVI for each year from 1985 to 2019. I want to take this image collection and create a single image where there are 35 bands, each band representing NDVI_1985... to NDVI_2019.

I think it would something like this:

```
var ndvi_collection = ndvi_coll.select(['nd_p95_rescaled','time'],['NDVI','time']);
print(ndvi_collection, "ndvi collection");

var multiband = ndvi_collection.iterate(function(image, result) {
  return ee.Image(result).addBands(image.select(['NDVI']));    
    }, empty);
```

The issue is that I want to carry over information about year in the band names or retain the 'time' band for each year as well.

Here is the link to the entire GEE script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a7fcc54f529ca1a43743f90b603a85b7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert an ImageCollection to an Image using the function `.toBands()`. For example:

```
var ndvi_image = ndvi_collection.select('NDVI').toBands();
```